# Can Kate (the text editor) display the number of times that a search term a user has entered in Find/Replace appears in a document?

Tags: kate

Chromium, for example, displays the number of times that a search term a user has entered in Find appears on a web page.

My use case is simple: when I search in Kate I would like to know how many times my search term appears in the document I am searching.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: Switch to `Search & Replace` mode via `Ctrl+R` and click on `Find All`. Then a popup will appear displaying the total number of found matches.